# Are there two meanings of the word shell?

Tags: terminology

The word "shell", in the context of an operating system means a user interface for the access of an operating system's services. I need to learn shell scripting now, in this context the definition says a shell is an environment in which we can run our commands, programs etc. 
 Is the meaning of the word shell different in both contexts?

Comment: Explain how they are different.

Comment: Even the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_(computing)) has the term _shell_ decently explained. Have patience to read it through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both in your context means the same. Technically, using shell scripting you are also  executing the commands by accessing the OS services. Shell is a user program or it's environment provided for user interaction. Shell is an command language interpreter that executes commands read from the standard input device (keyboard) or from a file. Shell is not part of system kernel, but uses the system kernel to execute programs, create files etc.

Comment: Why even in Windows system do we use UNIX shell scripting ? Please excuse my laymanship .

Comment: Even Windows now have a bash shell  where you can do UNIX shell scripting. See, the commands are specific to Operating System. Windows has its own different set of commands and UNIX has its own different set.

Comment: So , when we do shell scripting in windows that is for the shell of the windows opearting system ?